# List Counts show pending for long duration of time (hours)

Tags: list-manager, segmented-list

We are seeing an issue where the majority of a our lists counts now just show counts of "pending". 1 out of 10 refreshes will shows 50% of the lists with counts but with another refresh almost all go back to a count of "Pending". indexer shows no errors, xConnect shows no errors. Any thoughts on what is going on?

[image]

Comment: this error appear when the xConnect doesn't work as expected, have a look on searchIndexer logs

Comment: We have. In the last 24 hours we have only gotten one error. 
"Failed indexing next set of changes. There will be an attempt to recover from the failure."

This all started happening after a rebuild of the xDb index was canceled though. I would not think that would have this effect though since it was canceled so, in turn, the rebuild index is not being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a combination of a couple of things.

1. A large xDB contact database (60+ million).
2. The need to execute a segmentation rule against that database.
3. The need to execute a lot of segmentation rules at the same time (because you are looking at a list of segmentation lists so the rule has to run for all it is trying to show in the UI).

All this together means the system (SOLR) cannot execute and return the counts of all the lists with their segmentation rules applied fast enough to provide a count to the UI. So far the only answer has been a smaller database or bigger hardware.

Comment: Sitecore continuously evaluates Segmenged Lists (I think it caches the count for max 5 min), so if you have many Segmented lists or a Segmented List with a "complex" rule set, then it can indeed take a long time. 

It all depends on the amount of data and your SOLR setup, however some rules that you can select within a Segmented List are implemented so poorly that the query that is executed is extremely slow. 

To overcome issues it's a good idea to remove lists when you're done with them.